# Problems with authentication in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I changed my users table. It worked perfectly with the previous table 'panel_users', and I changed table to 'admins' in User model:

```
protected $table    = 'admins';
```

and in AuthController:

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => 'required|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:admins',
    'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed'
]);
```

Registration works just fine, but when I try to login with right credentials, page refreshes and error "These credentials do not match our records." occurs.

Table 'admins' has the same fields with my previous table, and some extra ones.

Comment: Only thing I can imagine is that some auth file like `config/auth.php` is hardcoded to use the `users` table. If you want different user roles by the way, it's probably easier and smarter to use a `user_roles` table which you link to your `users` table. Very interested in the answer anyway.

Comment: @Loek In my `config/auth.php` table name is not hardcoded. I use Eloquent instead. 
Unfortunately, I have to use the database which wasn't created by me :) Roles are in the different table, I just need to use exactly this one for all users regardless the role.

Answer (score 0):

As @Loek said, you need also make changes in `config/auth.php` file:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "Database" authentication driver, we need to know which
| table should be used to retrieve your users. We have chosen a basic
| default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
|
*/
'table' => 'users',
```

Comment: In my auth.php I use Eloquent instead: 
`'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
    ],`

Thanks for answering anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, problem was in the imported table. I've rewritten it with migrations, and everything works now.